# Meaning of t (coefficient) in probability generating functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, generating-functions

Given X non-neg random variable and some $g_{X}(t) = E t^X = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^nP(X=n)$

I am not sure what does "t" represent and how it relates to X?

What are the possible values for "t"? I saw examples of setting t=0, t=1, |t| <= 1 etc, but still not sure about it.

Maybe this is a basic question but a bit lost on how it *relates* to X.

Could you please explain?

Thanks

Comment: $t$ is just a dummy variable. It's for whatever $t$ such that the sum/integral converges

Comment: Thank you. I understand it could be any variable instead of t such as "z", "s", etc. I guess I am more confused about the possible values of that variable - it could only be from -1 to 1? What is the idea behind setting to 0 or 1? Can it take t=0.5?